# How can I modify stylesheet rules to add a descendant selector to the front of every rule using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I have user-supplied (arbitrary) css that is delivered as a single text string. This string can be stuffed into a style tag, and I can get a DOM element back from that if need be.

This css should only apply to part of the entire document, which I'll be wrapping in a div with a unique id. Given a rule that looks like this

```
.userclass > .whatever {
 background: blue;
}
```

... I'd like to be able to add `#uniqueid` in front of each rule so that it looks like

```
#uniqueid .userclass > .whatever {
 background: blue;
}
```

This seems non-trivial. I don't believe it's something I can manage in with a clever regex. Are there any methods in javascript that make this easy, or at least manageable?

If the css is put into a style tag, then it becomes possible to access each rule individually via index with .cssRules[n], but even then each rule can target multiple selectors. Is it as simple as a regex substitution there, looking for commas in between that and the first open curly bracket? Is there more to it than this?

Consider that any arbitrary (valid) css might be supplied.

Comment: I would recommend to send this file to sass preprocessor on backend. Then you can import that css (as scss) and do `#uniqueid { @import 'user-styles.scss' }`. JS string manipulation on frontend will be probably far from bulletproof..

Comment: Thanks @bigless . I will look into this.

Comment: @bigless This is indeed a good approach. I've thrown the ugliest css I can think of at it, and it's returning what I'd hope for. I was dreading trying to figure out how to parse all of this, turns out I don't have to. If you'll write up an answer, I'll checkmark it.

Comment: Will do. Btw there is js sass compiler library for browser too, but I never used that..depends on your usecase..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to send this file to sass preprocessor on backend. Then you can import that css (as scss) and do `#uniqueid { @import 'user-styles.scss' }`. JS string manipulation on frontend will be probably far from bulletproof..

Answer (score 1):

A simple aproach: 
If you get the style tag as a string and split it at } and add your #uniqueid at the beginning of each array element. Subsequently you just have to loop through the array and convert it back to a single string and append it to the html.

I don't know if you have jQuery but a solution in jQuery would look like that. 
This works for every CSS-Code. You can beautify the output if wanted with some additional tweaking.

```
var style = $('style').text();
style = style.split('}');
var newStyle = '';
$.each(style,function(i,element){
    newStyle = newStyle + ' #uniqueid '+element+' } ';
})
$('style').text(newStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its a one time affair I'd personally just do it quick-and-dirty...

https://www.sassmeister.com/

```
#uniqueid {
 // paste all your css
}
```

If this is going to be more regular you definitely want to implement a preprocessor in you build process.